# inserting data into database using codeigniter framework not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Why insertion operation is not working, my database is not accepting the data I am trying to insert. I have used autoload config to load database and New_model class.

New_controller.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class New_controller extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index($id)
    {
        //$this->load->model("New_model");
        $data["posts"]=$this->New_model->database($id);

        $this->load->view("New_view",$data);
    }

    public function insert_post()
    {
            $this->New_model->create([  
            'post_title'=>'health is wealth',
            'post_description'=>'as we know health is a gift of nature we should take care of our self',
            'post_author'=>'krishna',
            'post_date'=>'2016-01-19'
            ]);
    }
}
?>
```

I have used autoload config to load New_model class.everything seems to be fine but my insertion operation is not working

```
New_model.php
<?php

class New_model extends CI_Model {

    public function database($id)
    {
        //$this->load->database();
        //$sql=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");

        $this->db->where("id",$id);
        $sql=$this->db->get("posts");

        $result=$sql->result_array();

        return $result;
    }
    public function create($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert("posts",$data);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an array within your `create` function try using `print_r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Change this to**

```
$this->New_model->create([  
            'post_title'=>'health is wealth',
            'post_description'=>'as we know health is a gift of nature we should take care of our self',
            'post_author'=>'krishna',
            'post_date'=>'2016-01-19'
            ]);
```

**this**

```
$data = array(
        'post_title'=>'health is wealth',
        'post_description'=>'as we know health is a gift of nature we should take care of our self',
        'post_author'=>'krishna',
        'post_date'=>'2016-01-19'
    );

$this->New_model->create($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert data you have to create your array as

```
function insert_post() {
    $datanew = array(
        'post_title' => 'health is wealth',
        'post_description' => 'as we know health is a gift of nature we should take care of our self',
        'post_author' => 'krishna',
        'post_date' => '2016-01-19'
    );
    $this->New_model->create($datanew);
}
```

Read http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html

Comment: Check updated!! have you load your model in autoconfig.php file??

Comment: use `$sql = $this->db->last_query();` to print your query